# No transition for specific pages in core-animated-pages

Tags: polymer

In `core-animated-pages` with transitions, how do I specify a particular page **not** to have transitions?

Example, page 1 has no transition effect but pages 2 and 3 do.

```
<core-animated-pages fit selected="0" transitions="slide-from-right">
  <section>
    <div><!-- No transitions for page 1! --></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div><!-- Page 2 slides from right --></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div><!-- Page 3 slides from right --></div>
  </section>
</core-animated-pages>
```